# Escaping < to &lt; inside an attribute

Tags: xml, escaping, wso2-esb

I'm transferring an XML from one system to the other and modify just a few values.

But while comparing input and output, I can see that also the value of an attributes has been changed automatically.

I receive following element with an attribute:

```
<element coding_line="5508&gt;000000000000102608903458255+ 010851630&gt;"/>
```

But when I then check my output, it has automatically been changed to this:

```
<element coding_line="5508>000000000000102608903458255+ 010851630>"/>
```

It seems that my system (WSO2) did un-escape the `&gt;` to `>`.

My Question is now - **is the content of this attribute semantically still the same?**

Because I have not the permission to change this value. When I open the file in oXygen, it still seem to be a valid XML.

XML comparison:
[image]

Comment: *"while comparing input and output ..."* exactly *how* are you comparing input and output? With a plain text diff tool? Wrong tool for the job. (And yes, `>` is allowed unescaped in attribute values, unlike `<`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My Question is now - **is the content of this attribute semantically still the same?**

Yes, the presence of a literal `>` character in an XML attribute value is in line with the spec.

Therefore, upon parsing, these two XML samples represent equal documents:

```
<xml attr="&gt;" />
```

and

```
<xml attr=">" />
```

This fact, and quite a few others, like

- the fact that the source code order of attributes has no semantic meaning
- the rules regarding newline and whitespace normalization
- different forms of character representation (numerical character entity vs. actual character)
- namespaces (different prefixes, default namespaces, differing points of declaration, etc)
- the concept of "insignificant whitespace"

cause that normal (i.e. plain-text oriented) DIFF tools are ineffective in comparing XML files.

There are diff tools made especially for XML. For example Microsoft has the [XML Diff and Patch GUI Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302295.aspx) and there is [diffxml](http://diffxml.sourceforge.net/) or the [xmldiff Python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmldiff) and the [XMLunit Java package](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/).